# PHP exec fails when called from a browser but not from CLI

Tags: php, git, webhooks

I have a simple PHP script:

```
exec('git pull origin master', $shell_output, $output);
print_r($shell_output);
print_r($output)
```

When I call this via CLI `php git.php`, it works fine. I get the expected output, and a return value of 0. When I visit the page via a web browser, it fails with a return value of 1.

I've set file permissions to 777, and ensured `php.ini` doesn't block the `exec()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with some help by Ates Goral.

To debug the issue, I ran:

`sudo -u www-data php git.php`

to see how the script behaved when run under the `www-data` user. There were two issues:

`www-data` did not have its own public key. I created one and added it to the github repo.
And the `.git` folder was not readable by `www-data`. This was fixed by `chown`ing the directory to give permissions to the group `www-data` that both I and apache belong to.

Answer (score 3):

The CLI runs with the currently logged in user's (you) credentials and it's most probably different from what the web server process uses. Do a `exec('whoami')` etc. to verify.

Comment: The current user and the user apache runs under are both in the same group, and the file has `777` permissions. Should that not mitigate the issue?

Comment: Doesn't git need to know who is issuing the `git` command to determine the SSH key etc.? Are you pulling from a public repo?

Comment: Oh! I see now. the user I am has an sss key setup to access the repo, but the user apache runs under doesn't.

Comment: Any suggestions how I can get around this issue? Is there a way to create an ssh key for `www-data`, or run the git command through another user?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know the best practices around this. But executing git commands over a public HTTP request doesn't seem to be a very common/safe use case to me. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Automatic deployment via Github's webhooks when I push something to master. The code I posted in my question is only a snippet. I ensure the request is coming from one of GIthub's three Webhooks IPs

Comment: Oh I see. It's a legit use case :) I'll leave it to others to recommend solutions as I would only mindlessly be speculating.

Comment: Perhaps extend your question with the newfound knowledge to target the exact problem you're trying to solve. You'll increase your chances of getting a quick answer.