# Git via PHP & SSH: ssh authentification of user apache denied

Tags: php, linux, git, apache, ssh

I have the following setup: CentOS 6.5, git (client), apache 2.2, running test site etc. Goal is to create a remote browser-level access to execute "git pull". There is a general way to implement such thing using PHP. Lets say I have 2 scripts, one is php (it's being called to be executed directly via browser), another is shell scripts - gitpull.php and gitpull.sh, respectively.

### gitpull.php (it's in the same folder as index.php) contents:

```
<?php
$message=shell_exec("/var/www/html/...PATH-TO-INDEX.PHP.../gitpull.sh 2>&1");
?>
```

---

### gitpull.sh contents:

```
cd /var/www/html/...PATH-TO-FOLDER-WHERE-.GIT-WAS-INITIALIZED
git pull origin master:master
```

---

As I understand it, by calling up a php script all the following actions are to be performed as "apache" user, hence I have rsa keys created via `sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Both keys are in `~/.ssh` directory (apache is set up to access them), as well as copies in `/var/www` (apache home folder by default, I did it to avoid confusion in case apache uses keys only from there). I assume the location of keys does not matter as long as they are registered in sss using "ssh-add". Apache has permissions to access all relevant files/folders.

I figured that my problem is not in scripting, so I decided to check:

```
# ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

(works great, key is accepted), then

```
# sudo -u apache ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

returns

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Question: what did I miss in my setup? Why apache cannot be identified by its ssh key? If I'm wrong in working derictories, then where the keys must be in order for apache to use them with ssh? Could it help scripting ssh access in some customized way?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/260756/allow-scp-ssh-for-www-data-user

Comment: Try this command: `sudo -u apache ssh -T git@bitbucket.org -vvv` - you should see it offering the key you created for the apache user. You also need to make sure you uploaded the public part of that keypair to bitbucket

Comment: End of debug report: // input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1..... // sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA ..... // Enter passphrase for key [key location] // [blank space = no passphrase] // no passphrase given, try next key // we did not send a packet, disable method // no more authentification methods to try // Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: I would assume it requires the passphrase to be present, but as far as I know, that's not true. So apache user actually tries to use the given key, only it all falls apart on passphrase, which cannot be really the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your ssh public key in your bitbucket account ?

Comment: Yes. I made two keys spicifically under user "apache". They are present on the machine in "ssh-add -l" and in the folder ~/.ssh/authorised_keys. Public rsa is on bitbucket account, of course. So I have no idea what trips apache up.

Answer (score 0):

> To debug the issue, I ran: sudo -u www-data php git.php

This answer help by showing how to debug!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13097666/2614353